# error occurred while updating the object context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

first of all here is the message

> The changes to the database were
>   committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object
>   context. The ObjectContext might be in
>   an inconsistent state. Inner exception
>   message: A referential integrity
>   constraint violation occurred: The
>   property values that define the
>   referential constraints are not
>   consistent between principal and
>   dependent objects in the relationship.

the problem happens when i try to insert new data in the entityframework

---

My entity model

[image]

in the database i set the relation to cascade on delete and update. that is the only change i made to the relation

---

My Action Method :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompleteRegisteration(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = new User
                       {
                           DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
                           FullName = model.Name,
                           Email = model.Email,
                       };
        user.AuthenticationTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
                                          {
                                              ClaimedIdentifier = model.ClaimedIdentifier,
                                              DisplayName = model.Email
                                          });
        _userRepository.InsertOrUpdate(user);
        _userRepository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

---

and the user repository methods :

```
    private readonly StoryWritingEntities context = new StoryWritingEntities();

    public void InsertOrUpdate(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Attach(user);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user,
                                                     user.Id == default(int)
                                                         ? EntityState.Added // if true then this is a new entry
                                                         : EntityState.Modified); // if false this is an Existing entry

    }
    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

---

the problem is caused by `context.SaveChanges()` there is a record inserted in the users table but nothing is inserted in the AuthenticationTokens table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply did the following this wouldn't happen:

```
  context.Users.AddObject(user);
  content.SaveChanges();
```

I suspect the problem is occurring because EF doesn't know about the `AuthenticationToken` object, it's not being attached to the context because it's added to a disconnected entity which is then attached to the context.

You either need to let EF handle the whole object graph connectivity situation or you need to do it all yourself.  Mixing and matching like this doesn't work.

Comment: Would the `context.Users.Add(user)` bit be allowing EF to handle the whole object graph?

Answer (score 1):

Try something different, like:

```
if(model.Id != null)
{
    UpdateModel(user);
}
else
{
    _userRepository.Insert(model)
}
_userRepository.Save();
```

And the _userRepository.Insert would be:

```
public void Insert(User user)
{
    context.Users.AddObject(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was trying to edit a record/row in the table, but the code was adding a row with the same ID.

So I just changed the

```
ctx.table.Add(entity object);
```

too

```
ctx.Entry(entity object).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

> in the database i set the relation to
>   cascade on delete and update

1) I believe that if you setup cascading delete directly in the database you also need to define it in your model. The settings in the model designer are in the properties window of the relevant association (click on the association line between the two entities in the designer surface, then select "Properties").

2) I also believe that cascade on update is not supported in EF. Try to remove cascade on update in the database and check if it works then.